# Plot histogram for discrete data

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I'm struggling a lot to plot histogram using R for the following data:

```
ip_addr_player_id,event_name,level,time_to_finish,

118.93.180.241, Puzzle Complete, Puzzle 1,33.28 seconds
```

This is a single row of data. I need to pot histogram of the number player vs the number of levels played. I was able to successfully plot scatter plot, points, lines etc. but no histogram.

```
on Xaxis: number of levels. 
Yaxis: Number of player.
```

[image]

Each ip address is unique and multiple levels can be played by single ip address. I have attached a sample picture.

Comment: Histograms are for continuous data. You want a bar chart.

Answer (score 13):

I think what you are looking for is actually a bar plot, not a histogram. `geom_bar` is meant to be used for that. For example:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(diamonds, aes(cut)) + geom_bar()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

table() should do the job:

Creating data:

```
ips <- sample(seq(100,999), 100, replace = TRUE) 
levels <- sample(LETTERS, 100, replace = TRUE)
data <- data.frame(ips, levels)
```

now counting:

```
unique.levels <- sort(unique(data$levels))
count <- table(data$levels)
count.df <- data.frame(unique.levels, count)
```

Now plot:

```
plot <- ggplot(count.df, aes(unique.levels, Freq, fill=unique.levels))

plot + geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
        labs(title="Level Count",
             subtitle="count for every lvl played",
                     y="Count", x="Levels") + 
        theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image: plot]

I know that geom_bar() alone  will count levels for you if you use data$levels in aes(), BUT count.df carries that info so you can use it elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks ! for your suggestion. But this exactly not what I need. As you can see in the sample picture in my problem statement, I want it no of levels played vs number of players not per player.
for example :
p1 : l1,l2,l2 (pl player  3 levels of game)
p2: l3,l1     (p2 played 2 levels of game)
p3: l1     (p3 played 1 level of game)

so required histogram will be like :
x axis : (num of levels)    1     2     3    4   5 .....
y axis : (num of player)   1      1     1  
something like that

Comment: Hey ! thanks, I could solve my problem. I have the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(ip_addr_player_id='118.93.180.241', 
                 event_name='Puzzle Complete', 
                 level='Puzzle 1',
                 time_to_finish='33.28 seconds')
df$num_levels <- strsplit(var,split =' ')[[1]][-1]
ggplot(df) +geom_bar(aes(num_levels)) +labs(x="Num Levels",y="Num Players")
```